Jenkins with semantic release
I install semantic release by add this command on package.json:
  "release": "npx -p @semantic-release/changelog@^5.0.0 -p @semantic-release/git@^9.0.0  -p semantic-release@^17.0.0 semantic-release --no-ci --debug"

(my project is React) but when I commit the changes with feat or fix message on branch named "Work" nothing happened because changes happen on main branche and To resolve that I added .releaserc.json with this script:
{
  "branches": ["master", "work"]
}

but this error showed when I start the pipeline:
Error: Command failed with exit code 128: git tag v1.2.4 91ccded19a98200589df2bf338e866984906ccb0
fatal: tag 'v1.2.4' already exists


If you go to your Git host and head over to the tags section, you will see that this tag is already there. Your pipeline is trying to re-create the tag, which is when this error shows up. To solve the problem, go to your Jenkins workspace and  delete all the local tags:
git tag | xargs git tag -d

